# Filter on Formatted value and not on Model binding

Tags: javascript, sapui5

We have an sap.m.Table and in one column the value is formatted and shown in UI. 
SO, lets assume the data coming from Backend is : "EventDateTime":"2017-04-05T12:32:35.276Z".

We also receive the time zone for such a timestamp.

Now, we convert the received data using the time zone and show that data in : 06:32 04/04/2017 format.

Now, we need to apply column filter to table. As you can see there is a **difference in the backend value and the value which is shown on the screen** ( Data visible is a day behind due to time zone conversion). Now, we would like to apply the filter on formatted value shown in UI rather than the value which is present in UI.

So currently we have a basic filter for date like :

`new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    path: sPath,
    operator: "BT",
    value1: aValue[1],
    value2: aValue[2]
  })`

Consider this dummy data :

```
{  
   "root":[  
      {  
         "EventDateTime":"2017-03-14T17:04:22.856-05:00",
         "CreateDateTime":"2017-03-10T19:38:11-05:00",
         "WaybillId":827xxxx330697,
         "WaybillSerialNumber":60xx4277,
         "KillReason":"EMPTY",
         "KillDateTime":"2017-03-29T22:20:00-05:00",
         "WaybillNumber":2xx71,
         "ServiceOrderDateTime":"2017-03-10T19:38:00-05:00",
         "EventTimeZone":"EST",
         "CreateDateTimeZone":"EST"
      },
      {  
      {  
         "EventDateTime":"2017-04-14T17:04:22.856-05:00",
         "CreateDateTime":"2017-03-10T19:38:11-05:00",
         "WaybillId":82784xxx0697,
         "WaybillSerialNumber":6033xxx4277,
         "KillReason":"EMPTY",
         "KillDateTime":"2017-03-29T22:20:00-05:00",
         "WaybillNumber":2xx2071,
         "ServiceOrderDateTime":"2017-03-10T19:38:00-05:00",
         "EventTimeZone":"MDT",
         "CreateDateTimeZone":"IST"
      }
      }
   ]
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a `test` function to the Filter, returning `true` or `false` according to your condition:

```
    new sap.ui.model.Filter({
        path: sPath,
        test: function(value){ // value is the actual value from the cell
        return value === yourCondition; //here you check the value against your condition
      }
});
```

EDIT: Filtering by multiple conditions

```
new sap.ui.model.Filter({filters: [
                        new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                            path: sPath,
                            test: function (value) { // value is the actual value from the cell
                                return value === sQuery; //here you check the value against your condition
                            }
                        }),
                        new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                            path: sPath2, //Same or different path
                            test: function (value) { 
                                return secondCheck(value); //different condition
                            }
                        })
                    ], and: true //set to false for "or" behaviour
})
```

EDIT 2: Passing the root element as a sPath

```
new sap.ui.model.Filter({
            path: "", //Instead of matching "{EventDateTime}" we bind the entire object
            test: function(value){ 
            return isEqual(value.EventDateTime, value.EventTimeZone);
          }
    });
```

Documentation: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html

Comment: I need multiple values to be passed to the Test function. Is there any way to pass the entire current node to the test function ? I'm stuck there.

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj I expanded my answer with an array of filters. You can group and combine the `Filters` as you would with logical conditionals. Is that what you need? If you feel like you need to pass the entire node to the `test` function, it might mean that your sPath is too specific. You can even try with an empty `sPath` ("") if you want to pass the entire object to the function.

Comment: Thank you but I need both values at the same time. Based on 2 parameter, I modify 1st parameter and then I can return true or false.

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj Can you show us the model of the Table? That would make it easier for us to help you. Are those two parameters part of the same object?

Comment: Added the dummy data

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj You could try doing something like: `...Filter({path: '', test: function(value){...}}))`. Passing an empty string to the `path` you will get the whole object as your `value`. Then you can do `value.EventDateTime` or `value.EventTimeZone`, etc in the body of the `test` function. If this helps I will add it to the answer

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj Updated

Comment: I have a similar case but my sap.m.Table is bound to an oData source. Can I use custom filter with oData sources too?